# Processing error message, how should I write the drawgrid function?

Tags: processing

It always tells me I am mixing active and static mode.

```java
final int GAP = 15;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  background(255);
  drawGrid(mouseX,mouseY);
}

drawGrid(mouseX,mouseY)
{
  line(10,10,20,20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two syntax errors:

1. You're missing the return type for the drawGrid function (which I presume is `void` and Processing assumes you're making a call, not defining a function)
2. You haven't specified the types for the drawGrid's arguments

Try this:

```
final int GAP = 15;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  background(255);
  drawGrid(mouseX,mouseY);
}

void drawGrid(int mouseX,int mouseY)
{
  line(10,10,20,20);
}
```